# Return a sql query to a txt file - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

So, below is my code. I need to return the results of a sql query into a txt file.
When I do, on my txt file, the result is not the result of the query, but only the name "object"

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sql = require('mssql');
const connStr = require('./connStr.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
     
    
dotenv.config();
        
 async function save(content, fileName) {
  const filePath = process.env.RET_PATH
  await fs.writeFileSync(filePath + fileName,content)
};


async function sqlSelect (query) {
  
  await new sql.ConnectionPool(connStr).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.query(query)
  }).then(result => {
    return save(result.toString(),'test.txt')
  }).then(() => {
    return sql.close()
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
  
 
}
sqlSelect('select * from invoice')
```

Steps to reproduce:
1 -  I'm using node.js v14
2 - node-mssql to connect tp Mssql instance
3 - env file with the params to connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` returns an object, if you want to print result in the file you should `use JSON.stringify(result);`, if you want to print just a part of the object in the file you should use `result.partYouNeed.toString();`